# Redirecionar página com post usando ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Sei que a pergunta é muito estranha, mas é uma necessidade que temos, preciso passar para uma outra página algumas variáveis que resgatei, mas não é somente passar mas redirecionar a página também.
Não posso usar um window.location, precisa ser por post.

O que tenho no momento, o retorno está me exibindo as variáveis que preciso passar, mas como disse preciso redirecionar.

```
function preparaPagina() {

    $('button.inline-button').click(function() {

        var self = $(this);
        var IdCota = self.siblings('.product-info').data('idcota');
        var IdProduto = self.siblings('.product-info').data('produto');
        var IdUsuario = self.siblings('.product-info').data('usuario');
        var NomeUser = self.siblings('.product-info').data('nome');

        dados = {"IdCota": IdCota, "IdProduto": IdProduto, "IdUsuario": IdUsuario, "NomeUser": NomeUser  };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'iCadAutorizacaoTrans.php',
        data : dados,
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    })
}

preparaPagina();
```

Comment: `window.location` dentro do callback sucess não funcionaria?

Comment: Se não eu não entendi isso: Não posso usar um window.location, precisa ser por post.

Comment: Isso que mesmo Marconi, preciso passar essas variáveis e redirecionar para a página que estouro enviando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na função `success` do Ajax você pode inserir um `form` na página colocando os valores em cada `input` com seu respectivo `name` e submetê-lo via `method="post"`, redirecionando a página para a página destino declarada na variável `url_` (veja comentários explicativos no código):

```
function preparaPagina(){

   $('button.inline-button').click(function(){

      var self = $(this);
      var IdCota = self.siblings('.product-info').data('idcota');
      var IdProduto = self.siblings('.product-info').data('produto');
      var IdUsuario = self.siblings('.product-info').data('usuario');
      var NomeUser = self.siblings('.product-info').data('nome');

      var dados = {"IdCota": IdCota, "IdProduto": IdProduto, "IdUsuario": IdUsuario, "NomeUser": NomeUser  };

      // url do post
      var destino = 'iCadAutorizacaoTrans.php';

      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: destino,
         data : dados,
         success:function(data){
            console.log(data);

            // monta o formulário
            // note que o atributo "hidden" faz com que ele fique oculto
            var formulario = '<form id="form" hidden method="post" action="'+destino+'">'
            +'<input name="IdCota" value="'+IdCota+'">'
            +'<input name="IdProduto" value="'+IdProduto+'">'
            +'<input name="IdUsuario" value="'+IdUsuario+'">'
            +'<input name="NomeUser" value="'+NomeUser+'">'
            +'</form>';

            // insere o formulário no body
            $("body").append(formulario);
            // faz o submit e remove o formulário
            $("#form").submit().remove();

         }
      });
   })
}

preparaPagina();
```

Comment: Excelente, muito obrigado @DVD, me ajudou demais, valeu.